# Read certain txt files from a directory in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 200 txt files in a directory and I am wondering how can I read and plot some of them.
Lets say that the files names are like

**1_Mark_slow** , **2_Mark_fast**, **3_Mark_slow**, **4_Mark_fast**, etc.

I would like to read all 'slow' files.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a listing of the contents of certain directory using [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html), and filter them using the asterisk. For example:

```
myPath='/home/digna/myfiles/';
files=dir( fullfile( myPath, '*slow') );
```

This will return a struct array with information about all the files which filename contains the word "slow". The fields of the structure are the following:

```
name
date
bytes
isdir
datenum
```

So you can read them by accessing the `name` field:

```
for i=1:length(files)
  file=files(i).name;
  filepath = fullfile( myPath, file );
  %open and read file using filepath
end
```

Please see Matlab's [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) command for cross-platform concatenation of file names.

Comment: First comment: use `fullfile` to concatenate file names - allows for cross platform code (not sensitive to windows \'s and linux /'s)

Comment: Second comment: avoid variable name `path` - this is a build in function name

Comment: @Shai, thanks for your comments and for improving my answer :)